# How to add distinct values in a multivalue field in solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene, multivalue, distinct-values

I have a multivalue field called category(which is also a store field) in which i need to add only distinct values

`<field name="category">value1</field>`
`<field name="category">value2</field>`

If I do a update as follows
`<add>`
`<doc>`
`<field name="id">E02</field>`
`<field name="category" update="add">value2</field>`
`</doc>`
`</add>`

I get the value2 stored twice 
`<field name="category">value1</field>`
`<field name="category">value2</field>`
`<field name="category">value2</field>`

I need to store/update only disctinct values in category fields which is a multivalue fields. How to do this solr?

Thanks in advance,
Jagadesh.

Answer (score 6):

This functionality has been added for Solr 7.3.

You can use the **add-distinct** atomic update action, instead of **add**

See the [Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11267?attachmentOrder=desc) (SOLR-11267) and the documentation in the [Reference Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/updating-parts-of-documents.html#atomic-updates):

> **add-distinct**
>
> Adds the specified values to a multiValued field, only if
> not already present. May be specified as a single value, or as a list.

Answer (score 2):

One can "set" instead of "add", to recreate a stored field in partial document updates. So if it is the case where you have all the field values,just stick them in a `Set` and then repopulate the field. You have all the data to recreate it because of `stored field` requirement.

Comment: If i try this, yes `value2`is saved once but the old values `value1` is lost.

Comment: you need to set all previous + yours if it's distinct

Comment: Jus a clarification. What if the field is not a stored field?

Comment: partial updates are applied only to Solr >= 4.0 and stored field is a hard requirement. There is no magic there, Solr needs it to reconstruct(delete and re-indexe) the underlying Lucene document, also increasing the _version_ number. In older versions you had to do it manually. Read more http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/